# Efficient algorithm for Euclidean distance on a lattice

Tags: list-manipulation, lattices, distance

I am unable to code the problem in Mathematica. For the problem, please see the attached image. Help in this regard will be greatly appreciated.

The statement of the problem is as follows:

Consider a finite chunk of a unit cubic lattice in five dimensions with the grid points specified by positive, negative and zero integer coordinates $(n_1,...,n_5)$ where $|n_i| \leq N$ and $N$ is the size of the grid. Develop an efficient algorithm that selects all the grid points that lie within the Euclidean distance $d_0 = \sqrt 5$ from the plane spanned by the two orthonormal vectors $u_1, u_2$ given by:

```
u1 = Sqrt[2/5] Table[Cos[2 Pi xx/5], {xx, 0, 4}];
u2 = Sqrt[2/5] Table[Sin[2 Pi xx/5], {xx, 0, 4}];
```

and prints two dimensional coordinates of the projections of the selected points onto this plane.

> [image: jpg]

Comment: Please do not post unsearchable images of text and equations.  Instead typeset using *MathJax*.

Comment: Please post the Mathematica code about the expressions.

Comment: Mathematica has the command [`EuclideanDistance`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EuclideanDistance.html) and [`Norm`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Norm.html) as built-in symbols. I suggest that read the docs following the links.

Answer (score 3):

Is this related to quasi-crystals perhaps? I seem to remember there's a similar projection scheme from 5D to construct 2D quasi-crystals, and likewise from 6D to construct 3D quasi-crystals (although I don't seem to be able to find a reference for it..)

In any case, here's an implementation - although I make no promises for "efficiency"

1. Define a `d`-dimensional integer lattice of extent `n` (note we make the numerical to gain some speed-up, should work with exact numbers too):

```
lattice[n_,d_:5] := N[Tuples[Range[-n, n], d]]
```

2. Construct the infinite plane and pre-compute [`RegionDistance`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionDistance.html) and [`RegionNearest`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionNearest.html) functions

```
u1 = Sqrt[2/5] Table[Cos[2 Pi xx/5], {xx, 0, 4}];
u2 = Sqrt[2/5] Table[Sin[2 Pi xx/5], {xx, 0, 4}];
reg = InfinitePlane[{0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {u1, u2}];
rd = RegionDistance[reg];
rn = RegionNearest[reg];
```

3. Select points within the specified distance

```
pts = Select[lattice[2], rd[#] < Sqrt[5.] &]
```

4. Project on the 5d-plane

```
projectedPts = rn /@ pts;
```

5. Finally, compute inner products with the specified vectors

```
Graphics[Point[#.Transpose[{u1, u2}] & /@ projectedPts]]
```

[image]

For completeness, the 6D-to-3D quasi-crystal I referred to works similarly:

```
Block[{τ = GoldenRatio, m},
 m = {{τ, 0, 1}, {τ, 0, -1}, {1, τ, 0}, {-1, τ, 
    0}, {0, 1, τ}, {0, -1, τ}};
 Graphics3D[Point[# . m & /@ lattice[2, 6]], 
  ViewPoint -> 10000 {0, 4/Sqrt[5], 5/Sqrt[3]}, Boxed -> False, 
  ImageSize -> 350]
 ]
```

[image]

(Note the result is 3D, but we project along one of the 5-fold axes of symmetry for visualization)

Comment: Thank you very much George Varnavides. It is really helpful. If you can help me, I have two more questions: (1) How can we plot the computational time of this algorithm as a function of N in the log-log axes?      (2) How can we tabulate the number of selected points as a function of N?